# why am i getting an UnboundLocalError after i add my while loop and if then else if statements?

Tags: python

Whats going on here?
It's a basic slot machine game but when i try and add my conditions for the coins and coin generating I get the `UnboundLocalError`.
The random numbers generate when i don't have my while loop and if then else if statements

```
import random

def main():
    coins = 50
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    while coins >= 0 or giveUp != yes:
        coins = (coins - 3)
        x = random.randrange(1, 7)
        y = random.randrange(1, 7)
        z = random.randrange(1, 7)
        x = x
        y = y
        z = z
        print (x + y + Z)
        if (x == y) or (x == z):
            if (x == 1):
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 2:
                coins = (coins +3)
                print = ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 3:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print = ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 4:
                coins = (coins +3)
                print = ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 5:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print = ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 6:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print = ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 7:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print = ("you win 3 coins")
            giveUp = (input("do you give up?"))

main()
```

Comment: What's the fun of `x=x , y=y, z=z` ?what are you trying to say ?

Comment: And you should say `giveup!='yes'` in the first checking condition

Comment: Could you explain this `if`-`elif`-code? According to the values that show up you'll always get the same result (except that you made an error and overwrite `print` in most cases).

Answer (score 2):

This assignment (also called "binding")

```
giveUp = (input("do you give up?"))
```

means `giveUp` is a local.

The `while`loop is trying to test this local variable before you have assigned to it (ie bound it)

You could fix this by setting `giveUp = "No"` before the `while` loop

Also the `yes` should probably be `"yes"`

Answer (score 0):

```
while coins >= 0 or giveUp != yes:
```

In here your loop condition is up to a variable called `giveUp`, but you're trying to define that variable in the loop. You have to define it before the loop first. The best solution is define `giveUp="No"` **before** the `while` loop. Also `input()` returns string so it must be;

```
giveUp="No"
while coins >= 0 or giveUp != "yes":
#codes
```

Another tip, you're using `or` operator, so if user type `no` even without any coins user still can play. You should change it to `and`;

```
while coins >= 0 and giveUp != "yes":
```

Now if user want to play, need coins and 'yes'

Comment: Thank you guys it was the capital z and the "yes"

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your code...
`print (x + y + Z)` name `Z` in your code is Upper.
Sure error in here.. and `print =`  name `print` should not follow the character `=`

Try this..

```
>>> import random
>>> def main():
    coins = 50
    x = 0
    y = 0
    z = 0
    while coins >= 0 or giveUp != yes:
        coins = (coins - 3)
        x = random.randrange(1, 7)
        y = random.randrange(1, 7)
        z = random.randrange(1, 7)
        x = x
        y = y
        z = z
        print (x + y + z)
        if (x == y) or (x == z):
            if (x == 1):
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 2:
                coins = (coins +3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 3:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 4:
                coins = (coins +3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 5:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 6:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            elif x == 7:
                coins = (coins + 3)
                print ("you win 3 coins")
            giveUp = (input("do you give up?"))


>>> main()
you win 3 coins
do you give up?3
12
12
9
7
12
9
14
10
15
you win 3 coins
do you give up?1
9
>>>
```